# Set a queue length for jQuery animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, queue

**Is there a way to set a queue length of animation functions?**

Imagine someone fires a jQuery animate function using the arrow keys. Now he dashes the arrow keys like crazy and has to wait for the queued functions to complete which may take a lot of time and may be confusing and nerve-wracking. I know you can stop() an animation but I want it to simply have a queue length of let's say three.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ea2YU/). Open it and hit your keys.

**Example code:**

```
var div = $(".bouncer");

function runIt() {
div
    .animate({ left: "+=200" }, 500 )
    .animate({ left: "-=200" }, 500 )
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode) {
        runIt();
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe you want http://api.jquery.com/stop/ Using stop on the element before animating it again will stop the previous animation

Comment: does it work on regular functions too?

Comment: You can't stop a function from executing outside of that function

Comment: and does .animate() provide a way to set the queue length?

Comment: I don't believe you can set a max, but you can check the queues current length with `.queue`. You could always check the queues length and then break out of the function if it's too long. http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: @JeffShaver I updated my question for .animate() only

Comment: @JeffShaver okay I figured it now thanks to your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of i know there is no direct method to do that, but try this :

```
var div = $(".bouncer");

function runIt() {
div.animate({left: "+=200" }, 500)
   .animate({left: "-=200" }, 500)
}

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode) {
    var len=div.queue("fx").length;
    if(len<=1)
      runIt();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle.net/kcCG5/4/